# Iteration through the HtmlDocument.All collection stops at the referenced stylesheet?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

Since "bug in .NET" is often not the real cause of a problem, I wonder if I'm missing something here.

What I'm doing feels pretty simple. I'm iterating through the elements in a `HtmlDocument` called `doc` like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** " + doc.Url + " ***");
foreach (HtmlElement field in doc.All)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Tag = {0}, ID = {1} ", field.TagName, field.Id));
```

I then discovered the debug window output was this:

```
Tag = !, ID =  
Tag = HTML, ID =  
Tag = HEAD, ID =  
Tag = TITLE, ID =  
Tag = LINK, ID =
```

... when the actual HTML document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Protocol</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="ProtocolStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body onselectstart="return false">
        <table>
            <!-- Misc. table elements and cell values -->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Commenting out the `LINK` tag solves the issue for me, and the document is completely parsed. The `ProtocolStyle.css` file exist on disk and is loaded properly, if that would matter. Is this a bug in .NET 3.5 SP1, or what? For being such a web-oriented framework, I find it hard to believe there would be such a major bug in it.

**Update:** By the way, this iteration was done in the WebBrowser control's Navigated event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few years, I returned to this code and finally discovered that the problem was that I walked through the `HtmlDocument.All` collection in the `WebBrowser.Navigated` event handler. The proper way to do this is to walk through the elements in `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`.

This mistake also caused embedded script code to seemingly "halt" parsing, exactly like the aforementioned `LINK` tags. In reality, it wasn't halting -- it just hadn't finished rendering the entire document yet.